# Pagination with json-server and React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to paginate JSON data that I am using with JSON server in React. I am currently using splice to break the data up into pages with 10 items per page. To get the data from each splice I have an unordered list where the list items are assigned the data. I actually want to just have pages and a next button rather than have each page listed at the top of the page, but I cant seem to wrap my head around it. I would like to use _page _limit. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// added axios to assist with API calls.
import axios from 'axios';

import './App.css';
import Card from './Card.js';
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar.js"
import star from './images/star.svg';
import wars from './images/wars.svg';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPeopleData();
  }

  getPeopleData(search) {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3008/people?_start=0&_end=9&q=' + search).then((response) => {
      this.setState ({
        people: response.data
      });
    });
  }


  //1. Using axios and decided to use the slice method rather than the _page _limit from https://github.com/typicode/json-server#slice
  limitPerPage (begin, end) {
    axios(`http://localhost:3008/people?_start=${begin}&_end=${end}`).then((response) => {
      this.setState ({
        people: response.data
      });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='content'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={star} alt="star-logo" />
          <span className='interview-text'>The Interview</span>
          <img src={wars} alt="wars-logo" />
        </div>


        <h2>Cards</h2>

        {/* Decided to display the card pages as a list. Each page holds 10 cards */}
        <ul className="card-pagination">
          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(0, 9)}>Page 1</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(10, 19)}>Page 2</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(20, 29)}>Page 3</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(30, 39)}>Page 4</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(40, 49)}>Page 5</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(50, 59)}>Page 6</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(60, 69)}>Page 7</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(70, 79)}>Page 8</a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(80, 89)}>Page 9</a>
          </li>
        
        </ul>

        {this.state.people.map((person) => {
          return <Card
                    key={person.id}
                    id={person.id}
                    name={person.name}
                    imageURL={('http://localhost:3008/' + person.image)}
                    birthday={person.birth_year}
                    planetList={this.state.planets}
                    homeWorld={person.homeworld}
                  />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    people: [],
    _page_limit: 10,
    currentPage: 0
  }
}

...

limitPerPage (begin, end, increase) {
  axios(`http://localhost:3008/people?_start=${begin}&_end=${end}`).then((response) => {
    this.setState ({
      people: response.data,
      currentPage: this.state.currentPage + increase
    });
  });
}

_renderLinks() {
  var cp = this.state.currentPage
  if (cp == 0) {
    // show only "Page 1" and "Next"
    return (
      <ul className="card-pagination">
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li><a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage(10, 20, 1)}>Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    )
  } else if (cp < this.state._page_limit - 1) {
    // show "Back", "Page X" and "Next"
    return (
      <ul className="card-pagination">
        <li><a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage((cp-1) * 10, cp * 10), -1}>Back</a></li>
        <li>Page {(cp + 1}</li>
        <li><a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage((cp+1) * 10, (cp+2) * 10, 1}>Next</a></li>
      </ul>
    )
  } else {
    // show "Back", "Page X" and "Next"
    return (
      <ul className="card-pagination">
        <li><a onClick={() => this.limitPerPage((cp-1) * 10, cp * 10, -1)}>Back</a></li>
        <li>Page {(cp-1)}</li>
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

render() {
    var _page_limit = 10
    return (
      <div className='content'>
        <div className='logo'>
          <img src={star} alt="star-logo" />
          <span className='interview-text'>The Interview</span>
          <img src={wars} alt="wars-logo" />
        </div>


        <h2>Cards</h2>

        {this._renderLinks()}

        {this.state.people.map((person) => {
          return <Card
            key={person.id}
            id={person.id}
            name={person.name}
            imageURL={('http://localhost:3008/' + person.image)}
            birthday={person.birth_year}
            planetList={this.state.planets}
            homeWorld={person.homeworld}
            />
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The expression `[...Array(_page_limit).keys()]` is a shortcut for creating an array of numbers between 0 and (_page_limit - 1), inclusive.

Comment: That cleans up the code a bit, but now it is only displaying 9 items per page and it is still displaying each page at the top rather than having a next button. Any ideas why it limited it to 9 per page and how I can get it to only list the page link the user is on rather than all 10 pages at once?

EDIT: I did change +9 to +10 to get 10 items per page.

Comment: I just checked that [json server slice link](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#slice) you had as a comment right before the `limitPerPage` function. It says `_start is inclusive and _end exclusive`. So I think changing `limitPerPage(num * 10, (num * 10) + 9)` to `limitPerPage(num * 10, (num * 10) + 10)` would change it from 9 to 10 per page. "only list the page link the user is on" - can you elaborate on that?

Comment: My guess is, say for example you're on page 4. You only want `back` and `next` buttons to act as clicking on pages 3 and 5, respectively (not showing the links for all 10 pages). And if you're on page 1, only show next button. If that's the case, you'll have to keep track of which page the user is currently on and render the links accordingly.

Comment: Your guess is exactly right. How would I got about keeping track of that and rendering that?

Comment: I partially update my answer to address keeping track of the page. Last part remaining is updating `this.state.currentPage` when new links are clicked

Comment: Edited again to include updating `currentPage`. Check how I added a third parameter to the `limitPerPage` function. When that's called from clicking a back button, the parameter is -1 to represent going to the previous page, and 1 when called from clicking a next button.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you. I think there may be some syntax errors possibly with some of the parentheses. I tried fixing it but my back button returns NaaN. Ill go through it some more. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148104/discussion-between-stuffedpoblano-and-pat-needham).